# Connectify not working properly?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, connectify

I use connectify to create a wifi hotspot which I use in my Android device. But a problem occurs that the internet access stops after a minute or so in my Android device. I have to restart connectify so that it works fine again, but again I face the same problem in a minute or so.

Its not a problem with my device as it runs properly on other wifi networks.

Any solution to this??

Comment: Sounds more like [superuser](http://superuser.com) would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: yep, I was in a dilemma where to post, so posted in both ;)

Comment: [Please do *not* cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 1):

Use a portable small utility [mHotspot](http://mhotspot.com) instead of Connectify. Connectify does have such type of issues. So, mHotspot is my all time favorite when it comes to creating virtual hotspot.

If you're unable to connect for the first time (which shouldn't be case as you were able to connect with AP of Connectify), reload the Wi-Fi driver by dialing `*#*#526#*#*` or install the "wifi-fixer" app from Play Store.

Comment: I shows that it requires .NET framework to be installed for it to run!

Comment: @gopi I wonder that .NET framework isn't already installed in your PC. Install it..

Comment: yep, had it, but uninstalled it since I dont develop in .NET PHP suits me. Any other alternatives?

Comment: You don't need to develop .NET to have the framework installed. It's part of the underpinnings of some rather good apps, like Paint.NET.

Comment: Why not use the alternative framework [Mono](http://go-mono.com)?

Comment: .NET framework is a virtual machine just like JVM. You should keep it. Many apps may require it. I don't know any other alternative.

Comment: there's no pleasing some people eh?! ;)

Comment: ohk.. fine.. I see this is going in a different direction. Fine I installed .NET @t0mm13b thanks for Mono, would be of help in my ubuntu OS.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Had to upvote your answer because something caught my eye [mHotspot's faq](http://mhotspot.com/faq.html) - See that bit about "*My Android device won't connect to the hotspot*" - TIL that you can actually reload the wifi from the phone dialler!!!!

Comment: @RichardBorcsik ? didn't get you.

Comment: @gopi1410 sorry, just ranting about PHP. It's awful and I hate to see people stuck with it.