# Connect Android phone to PC network via Bluetooth or Wi-Fi

Tags: internet

I use a USB dongle to use the internet, which I connect to my laptop. Then, I share the internet via Adhoc Wi-Fi network, but the network is not searchable on my pone.

I searched Google and found some software like Connectify. With this software, the network appears on my phone, but it keeps on scanning and never gets connected. Also, the network which I have created does not share it with other laptops.

Is there a free software through which I can connect with the laptop internet through Bluetooth or Wi-Fi? I don't like the internet pass through because I was unable to move my phone on my apartment with that option.

Comment: Android does, by default, not support [ad-hoc-networks](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ad-hoc-networks) -- which is what Connectify creates. What you are obviously looking for is [reverse-tether](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether) -- again not supported by default. Both would require [rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting) your device.

Comment: What android version are you referring to?

Comment: Please check if any of the methods described here: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/171049/209414 work for you. Also if you are having problems with Connectify check if this resolves the issues: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/171147/209414

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

1. If you are on a Windows machine, download [MyPublicWiFi](https://mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html) and install
2. Set desired network name (SSID) and Network key i.e password. Let Enable Internet sharing check box be checked in, and select the appropriate network connection from which you are accessing the internet on your PC or laptop.
3. Press “Set up and Start Hotspot“, this makes your PC a hotspot.
4. Now try connecting from your Android device

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps:

1. Open Settings.
2. Click Tethering and Portable hotspot.
3. Configure as desired.
4. Switch on the portable hotspot.
5. Follow steps for connecting to PC with Wi-Fi.
   NOTE: You cannot use Wi-Fi client and Wi-Fi hotspot simultaneous or use USB tethering method, follow steps:
6. Connect Android phone to computer using USB cable,
7. Open settings, then click Tethering and Portable Hotspot.
8. Click USB Tethering.
9. Activate Wi-Fi client (for USB tethering only).
10. Open the browser and type www.google.com to make connection.

Comment: Only operate this method if you cannot install apps.