# How do I make reverse tethering work?

Tags: networking, windows, internet, reverse-tether

I've been trying this for a couple of days and I've to say it's not getting any better. I've tried stuffs from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/214375/how-to-reverse-tether-an-android-smartphone-or-tablet-to-your-pc/) and [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494), but unfortunately none helped.

So if there is any alternative solution to use internet on my phone from my laptop please do humor me.

> Please do not suggest opening a hotspot from my laptop as my hardware doesn't support the hostednetwork capabilities.

Note : I'm running lollipop.

Comment: Have you already checked with out [reverse-tether tag-wiki](/tags/reverse-tether/info) and followed up to [How to use PC's internet on Android phone through USB cable](/q/73168/16575)? Several detailed instructions there. Tried them?

Comment: Please take a look here for more related methods: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/171049/209414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being confused and helpless for couple of days I found a very clean and simple solution that only involves installing a small app that neither needs root nor configuring anything on your laptop. (It needs drivers though.)

Fun fact: You can run this on all operating systems(Mac, Linux, Windows).

**Things to download**

1. [Reverse tethering app for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free&hl=en) (This app is free for download and gives 10 minutes of connection every 30 minutes.)
2. [Reverse tethering server app on Laptop](http://fdmobileinventions.blogspot.in/p/reversetethering-server.html)

**ReverseTethering Server Requirements**

1. Java Runtime Environment 1.7 or newer (Download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html))
2. x86 Processor

**Instructions**

1. Enable USB Debugging in the Developer System Settings on your device.
2. Connect your device to your computer via a USB cable.
3. If you are using Windows, you have to install USB drivers for your Android device now. These drivers are typically provided by the device manufacturer as a download. For some devices, Windows can automatically find, download and install the drivers when you connect your Android device for the first time. Please note there is a difference between MTP drivers (for file exchange) and ADB drivers (which RevTet needs). Many computers automatically install the MTP drivers, but not the ADB drivers. In order to find the appropriate ADB drivers for your device, please do an Internet research.

   (If need be: Download ADB drivers from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979).Takes less than a minute to install.)
4. On Linux, you have to set up your system to recognize the Android device.
   Download the right archive of the Reverse Tethering server application from above mentioned link.

> Unzip the downloaded file
>
> On macOS: Double-click ReverseTetheringServer.app
>
> On Windows: Double-click ReverseTetheringServer.exe
>
> On Linux: Double-Click ReverseTetheringServer.jar

**Also remember**

*Transfer rates are below average. You won't be getting A-one performance using this method.*

Comment: I'm the author of this app. The speed should actually match that of a Wifi connection.

Comment: @FD_ you are a life saver. Awesome work with the app. There is a small problem - Internet worked fine(Browsing through play store and instagram) but downloading from play store is not possible. Is there anything I should do?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) from Genymotion. It's the most simple solution I've come across.  There's no root required. The only requirements are that you should have Java 8 and recent version of adb configured.

Root: Not required

OS: Linux, Mac, Windows

Android device : Android 5.0+ [API 21]

Steps

1. Download the latest version of gnirehtet from this [link](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/releases/latest).
2. Extract the zip
3. Connect the phone to computer with usb debugging enabled
4. Run `./gnirehtet rt`
5. Accept the VPN request on phone and enjoy.
6. To stop, *Ctrl*+C

[image: VPN request gnirehtet]

References:

1. https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet
2. http://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html