# How to use PC data on phone via USB cord?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, tethering, reverse-tether, usb-tethering

One can use the mobile data from a PC using the USB tethering feature.

Is there any way to do the opposite, that is use the PC data from mobile, using USB cord or any other cord or app?

My phone is Samsung Galaxy On7 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Phone is not rooted.

Comment: Yes please check here for a comprehensive lists of methods to do that: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/171049/209414

Comment: I'll accept that if you give me a good app that can root and **unroot** my device.

Comment: Did you check the solution in question marked duplicate which offers an app for non rooted phones?

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU please check the solutions in both cases, im sure there is one for non rooted devices.

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU did you manage to resolve the problem?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I've found a method that does not require rooting (perhaps) at https://www.codeproject.com/kb/android/usbportforwarding.aspx . However, I've not tried it as I'm not at my home currently, as the PC is inaccessible. Will surely let you know if the above process works.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat  Even this might work: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free

Comment: Thats great! ya try these

Comment: The latter doesn't even require rooting the device, so that's even better. 