# Increase hotspot connection limit on Android

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I see this question has been asked several times over the years, but I don't really see a good practical solution. The question is - is there any way to increase the number of simultaneous connections to my Android hotspot? My limit is 8 connections.

So, my Android phone receives GSM data and I then turn on "Mobile Hotspot" to distribute this to other devices using WiFi.

8 connections seem to be very few these days especially with family members wanting to connect to it.

I'm curious as to why only Google limits it to 8, perhaps heat reasons as some devices are heavy on the data but then others a light. For example, my smart TV can stream Netflix or conversely, I have a Brilliant light using very little data.

Does anyone know of a way to modify hotspot? Perhaps using an app.

Comment: The phone was not designed to be a router.  Eight devices to feed from the phone is really generous.

Comment: Since Android is open-sourced and customizable, I guess the question is: is it Google that limits it, the manufacturer, or the mobile provider?

Answer (score -1):

> > I'm curious as to why only google limit it to 8, perhaps heat reasons as some
> > devices are heavy on the data but then others a light for example my smart
> > TV can stream Netflix or conversely I have a Brilliant light using very
> > little data.

Tech giants don't want us to use smartphones as power-frugal small computers.

Smartphones are designed to draw little power compared to PC's and servers, yet they are compact, fast, and equipped with a battery that lasts 2 days in case of blackout.

Do you think that Tech giants will allow us to replace PC's and servers with smartphones?

They already lost the servers' war with Linux and FreeBSD.

---

> > Does anyone know of a way to modify hotspot? Perhaps using an App.

I don't think we can.

I got an Android One phone. When I turn on the hot spot I can't change the address class of the the DHCP server. It's fixed.

All Wi-Fi chips have a hardware limitation: they can serve a maximum number of Wi-Fi stations (clients) because the Wi-Fi protocol has very strict timing requirements.

---

You may want to take a look at this answer here. I agree with that answer: the maximum number of clients is hard coded and it depends on the WiFi hardware chip that has limitations stated in its datasheet.

[Increase maximum number of connection of Wi-Fi hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186487/increase-maximum-number-of-connection-of-wi-fi-hotspot)

Comment: Good points made thanks but I tend to disagree.  While not specifically built as a router it is obviously acting as a router but with the number of Wi-Fi connections limited.  DHCP may have an IP class or perhaps a subnet mask set in order to acheive this. Other routers don't have any Wi-Fi limitations why would a smartphone network, I expect up to 254 connections with a class C network.  I expect a setting that let's me choose the max connections I desire.

Comment: This question may be closed but no progress made, no real explanation and no resolution.